# getting the table names and their row counts using a query in oracle db

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database and I want to get the names of the tables in that database along with the number of data rows in those tables.

```
select table_name from dba_tables where owner = 'owner'
```

returns the names of all the tables in the database, but I can't get the number of rows in each table.

Querying the num_rows column would not give the row count in real time since it requires all the tables to run the "analyze" command on them.

Is there a way to get both columns, the table name and the row count of each respective table using a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT 
   table_name, 
   num_rows,
   last_analyzed
FROM dba_tables
```

You may need to update statistics before:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(ownname => 'NAME');
```